# Structuring a sentence with two phrases qualifying the same ending

Tags: style, editing

For a long time, I have wondered which way of writing the following is correct.

(Is more than one correct?)

1. The expected result for integers denotes that a value should be **at least** a specific value **or at most** a specific value.
2. The expected result for integers denotes that a value should be **at least or at most** a specific value.
3. The expected result for integers denotes that a value should be **at least, or at most,** a specific value.

All the best, Patrick

Answer (score 3):

C is the clearest and easiest to read. The commas not only set off the interrupter to highlight it but give the reader a moment to pause and note the two items being discussed (*least* and *most*).

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question: all of your examples are grammatically correct. (Well done!)

However, in most contexts, clarity and readability are even more important than grammatical correctness. By that measure, your third example is definitely the best, as Lauren has explained so well.